# How to do `using` of weak enums in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, using

I have enum definition inside a class in the header:

```
namespace A {

class B {
 public:
  enum Value {
    VALUE1 = 1,
    VALUE2 = 2,
  };
};

}
```

And I want to use its values in a source file without prefix, like this:

```
#include "header"

int main() {
  someFn(VALUE1);

  return 0;
}
```

I have tried to `using A::B::Value;` but clang gives an error:

> using declaration can not refer to class member

---

Even if I move enum outside of a class:

```
namespace A {

enum Value {
  VALUE1 = 1,
  VALUE2 = 2,
};    

}
```

and do `using A::Value;`, the error is gone, but the compiler complains about `VALUE1`:

> use of undeclared identifier 'VALUE1'

Is there way to use values of enum without any prefixes, if the enum is defined somewhere else? - Using `#define`s is out of question.

If there is no way, then what is a possible issue about implementing such behavior in C++ Standard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two reasons why your approaches fail:

1. The first reason has been described by BЈовић: You cannot introduce the name of a nested type in a namespace scope, see [namespace.udecl]/8.
2. When you write `using A::B::Value;`, only the name of the `enum` itself will be introduced in the current scope, **not** the name of all enumerators. This allows things like:

   ```
   namespace Values { enum Value{ VALUE1, VALUE2 }; }
   using Values::Value;  // don't pollute my scope with the enumerators

   Value v = Values::VALUE1;
   ```

The second issue can be solved by introducing the enumerators individually:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        enum Value
        {
              VALUE1
            , VALUE2
        };
    }
}

int main()
{
    using A::B::Value;
    using A::B::VALUE1;
    using A::B::VALUE2;

    Value v = VALUE1;
    v = VALUE2;
}
```

Alternatively, as [hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743382/hvd) suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887425/how-to-do-using-of-weak-enums-in-c11#comment29586525_19887459), you can use a using-directive to introduce all names of a namespace:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        enum Value
        {
              VALUE1
            , VALUE2
        };
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace A::B;

    Value v = VALUE1;
    v = VALUE2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To put is simply : it is not possible, because enum is defined in the class.

If you change the `class B` into `namespace B`:

```
namespace A {

namespace B {
  enum Value {
    VALUE1 = 1,
    VALUE2 = 2,
  };
};

}
```

then it would be possible to do (as you wrote in your code):

```
using A::B::Value
```

Comment: But, as I mentioned, compiler (clang) gives an error: `use of undeclared identifier 'VALUE1'`

Comment: @abyss.7 that is weird. you should get "error: ‘A::B’ is not a namespace"

Comment: @abyss.7 Actually, it is telling you what I wrote in the answer. The error message I wrote is from g++.

Comment: Even, if the error message is different - this still doesn't work, for both of us.

Comment: @abyss.7 In your question, you wrote "and do `using A::Value;`," -- don't do that. Don't import just the `Value` name. Import the whole namespace, and make sure that that namespace is *only* for that one enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are treated in a manner similar to classes. Think of it as trying to do the following:

```
class Value
{
public:
    static const int VALUE1 = 0;
};

using Value::VALUE1; // ERROR class-qualified name
```

In short: You can't make enum values visible this way with a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the closest I can think of is:

```
namespace A {
  class B {
  public:
    enum Value { VALUE1 = 1, VALUE2 = 2 };
  };
};

const A::B::Value VALUE1 = A::B::VALUE1;

int main () {
  return VALUE1;
}
```

but its rather tedious and error prone and absolutely not worth it. :)

Comment: That's not a good approach, since I have to duplicate all enum values everywhere, where I want to use them.